# Не отображается Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

Пытаюсь добавить Toolbar в свое приложение, но сейчас вместо него отображается соответствующий размерам Toolbar белый прямоугольник без всего. Делал все по гайду: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) Но без результата впереди.

Так выглядит файл toolbarlayout.xml в папке menu:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.mazgutov.rail.app.HeroSelectActivity" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Hi"/>
    </menu>
```

Так выглядит layout activity в который хочу добавить Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".StartActivity"
        android:background="@mipmap/background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/button_start"
            android:onClick="onClickStart"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/heroes_list"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button_start"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_search_hero"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_search_hero"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cleaer selection"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            android:layout_below="@+id/heroes_list"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

В метод onCreate(..) этого Activity я добавил в следующие строки:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Это не сработало, я стал искать дальше и наткнулся на статью: [Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256643/) После этого в файле Activity появился метод:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbarlayout, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Где-то встретил, что кому-то помогло заменить предыдущий метод, на:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbarlayout, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Манифест моего приложения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mazgutov.rail.app">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:windowFullscreen = "true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TimersListActivity"
        android:label="Timers"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HeroSelectActivity"
        android:label="Heroes"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте у тулбара использовать `app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` тему, на крайний случай вот кусок разметки, при которой тулбар должен отображаться нормально - затем эксперементируйте, и посмотрите от чего это может быть.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/coordinatorBackground"
        android:clickable="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

я думаю, что проблема со стилями, в активити у вас все так , как нужно. Да и в разметке тоже.

Comment: К сожалению, даже использование этой разметки не дало результатов.